# How to load content from all tabs from angular ui tabset even when not active

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

I've been stuck on this for a while, I hope someone can help.

I have four different controllers and templates. One controller has a heading, a submit button, and 3 tabs in it.For the purpose of this question I will call it the parent controller, the module for this parent controller is `personManagement`

The tabset in parent.html looks like this:

```
<div>
   <h3> Main page title </h3>
   <div>
    <tabset>
       <tab role="tab" heading="General Info" ui-sref="tab1"></tab>
       <tab role="tab" heading="Detailed Info" ui-sref="tab1"></tab>
       <tab role="tab" heading="Related Info" ui-sref="tab1"></tab>
    </tabset>
    <div ui-view></div>
</div
```

Each of the controller uses `$stateprovider`

I am able to load each html tab correctly and switch around between tabs fine either manually in each tab controller using `$state.go` or `ui-sref`. However each tab has form data in it with some of the fields being required fields and I need to be able to verify that the required fields are all filled across the three different tabs before the Submit button is enabled in the parent html.

In the html for each tab, I use `ng-init` on each required field input box and call a function `checkAllRequiredFields` in the controller for that tab which checks whether all the required fields are filled. However, it will only check the ones in the current tab.

I tried moving the `checkAllRequiredFields` function to the parent controller and then used a factory like this

```
angular.module('myApp.personManagement').factory('RequiredFieldsFactory', function () {
    return { AllRequiredFields: [], checkAllRequiredFields: '' };
}); //this code is in the parent controller. The definition for the `checkAllRequiredFields` function is also declared in the parent controller..
```

Each time an input box is modified, the function in the parent controller is called but it always only knows about the required fields for the current tab. I am pretty sure it is because the other tabs are hidden until you navigate to those tabs and so the DOM only has the data from the current tab.

Is there a way around this so I can verify that all required field across all 3 tabs are filled so that the Submit button can be enabled?

Comment: Please make pluckr and add in question..

Comment: Give all the forms name and check if the forms are all valid in angular way. Eng:  `($scope.form1.$valid && $scope.form2.$valid)` Parent controler can access all the scopes of child templates